# Spark 2.2 Structured Streaming Stream - Static left outer join issue

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I seem to be missing something on the Stream - Static Join in Spark 2.2.

The manual states that such a join is possible, but I cannot get the syntax correct. Odd. No watermark being used.

```
val joinedDs = salesDs
  .join(customerDs, "customerId", joinType="leftOuter")
```

Error gotten is as follows, but I am pretty sure I have the sides right:

```
<console>:81: error: overloaded method value join with alternatives:
  (right: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[_],joinExprs: 
org.apache.spark.sql.Column,joinType: String)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  (right: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[_],usingColumns: Seq[String],joinType: String)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
 cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Customer], String, joinType: String)
         .join(customerDs, "customerId", joinType="left_Outer")
          ^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason when adding joinType I also needed to add the Seq.

```
  .join(customerDs, Seq("customerId"), "left_Outer")
```